# How to do sessions if client doesn't accept cookies? Understanding response.encodeURL() inside Servlet

Tags: java, session, servlets, session-cookies, urlencode

I am practicing maintaining sessions between client and server. For that I used simple solution with *JSESSIONID* stored inside cookie. So my little program works like this:

index.html:

```
<html><body>
    
    <form action="testing">
        <input type="text" name="animal">
        <button>Go</button>
    </form>
    
</body></html>
```

MyServlet.java (mapped in XML as */testing)*:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        String name = req.getParameter("animal");
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();

        pw.print("Welcome " + name + "<br>");

        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        if (session.isNew()) {
            pw.print("New session: " + session.getId() + "<br>");
        } else {
            pw.print("Old session: " + session.getId() + "<br>");
        }

        pw.print("<a href=\'index.html\'> Home </a>");
    }
}
```

So, if I submit something from FORM more than twice, Server should "find" my *JSESSIONID* stored in heap. Here is a picture of how it would look when FORM is submitted (I typed 'parrot' inside input):

[image]

But then I disabled cookies in my browser. After, my server never finds user's *JSESSIONID* because user never actually stores it anywhere. Remember that before, *JSESSIONID* was stored in a cookie, but since I disabled them, it can't possibly store it there anymore. So now, I am stuck.

What can I do in this case? I came across `response.encodeURL()` that uses URL and appends its *JSESSIONID* into URL. But I have trouble understanding how to implement it and how it works internally. Can someone tell me how to fix this using `encodeURL()` and actually explain how does code work after made such implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf), the server should support a few ways of tracking sessions: with cookies, SSL sessions, or URL rewriting.

You are asking about URL rewriting, which works like this:

> URL rewriting is the lowest common denominator of session tracking. When a client will not accept a cookie, URL rewriting may be used by the server as the basis for session tracking. URL rewriting involves adding data, a session ID, to the URL path that is interpreted by the container to associate the request with a session.
>
> The session ID must be encoded as a path parameter in the URL string. The name of the parameter must be jsessionid. Here is an example of a URL containing encoded path information:
>
> `http://www.myserver.com/catalog/index.html;jsessionid=1234`
>
> URL rewriting exposes session identifiers in logs, bookmarks, referer headers, cached HTML, and the URL bar. URL rewriting should not be used as a session tracking mechanism where cookies or SSL sessions are supported and suitable.

Notice that it's a path parameter, not a query parameter. Your query params will follow that, like this:

```
http://www.myserver.com/catalog/index.html;jsessionid=1234?param1=value1&param2=value2&...
```

This mechanism is supported automatically by the server to track sessions, but it becomes pretty obvious that you need to give the server a helping hand. And you do that by making sure that all your links include the `jsessionid` otherwise your server won't identify your request with a session.

You can use [`encodeURL`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL-java.lang.String-) in your Java code:

> Encodes the specified URL by including the session ID, or, if encoding is not needed, returns the URL unchanged. The implementation of this method includes the logic to determine whether the session ID needs to be encoded in the URL. For example, if the browser supports cookies, or session tracking is turned off, URL encoding is unnecessary.
>
> For robust session tracking, all URLs emitted by a servlet should be run through this method. Otherwise, URL rewriting cannot be used with browsers which do not support cookies.

You need to do the same inside your JSP files. That's usually done with something like [`<c:url>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html#bnakn) instead of writing URLs directly into the file:

> [...] You can use the url tag to rewrite URLs returned from a JSP page. The tag includes the session ID in the URL only if cookies are disabled; otherwise, it returns the URL unchanged. Note that this feature requires that the URL be relative. [...]

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can do. This is used to append your JSESSIONID to a url you would retrieve to the user, so they can navigate in it and maintain the information of who they are. About understanding how it works internally is simple as you see, it just append the id to a url you pass, how the user information are stored, is your function on the server side, you will use the id given by the user in the next requests to retrieve information to them.

```
/**
* Almost minimal processing for a servlet.
*
* @param nextUrl The url the caller would like to go to next. If
*                supplied, put an encoded url into the returned
*                html page as a hyperlink.
*/
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
   throws ServletException, IOException {

   resp.setContentType("text/plain");
   PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
   out.print("OK");

   String param = req.getParameter("nextUrl");
   if (param!=null) {
       // append an encoded url to carry the sessionids
       String targetUrl = resp.encodeURL(param);
       out.print(". You want to go <a href=\"");
       out.print(targetUrl);
       out.print("\">here next</a>.");
   }
}
```

Edit:
You put it in this part of your code

```
pw.print("<a href=\'" + resp.encodeURL("index.html") + "\'>Home</a>");
```